# Lazarus: Why does setfocus to TButton trigger the Click event

Tags: onclick, freepascal, lazarus, setfocus

This is a pretty big form but let me address only the relevant part.

I have text boxes (TEdit) for Qty Rate and Amount. Then I have a button (TButton) that runs some process.

I want the user to hit ENTER on the Qty box so that the focus would be on the button. So I did this:

```
procedure TfrmSalesEntry.txtQtyKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: char);
var
  Amount: Real;
  ItemErrors: Boolean;
begin

  ItemErrors:= False;
  if Key = chr(13) Then
     begin    
       if ItemErrors = false Then
          begin
         //Calculate Amount and move to Button;
         Amount := InvItemRecord.ItemPrice * StrToFloat(txtQty.Text);
         txtAmount.Text := FloatToStr( Amount );

         cmdAddItem.SetFocus;/////HERE'S THE PROBLEM

          end;        
     end;

end;
```

But the moment I hit ENTER, the BUTTON not only gets the focus, but it **also triggers a click**. Thus as a user, I don't have control if I decide not to click it.

Is it normal for a button to get clicked on getting focus or is there something else wrong (perhaps a bug).

I'm using:

Lazarus 1.0.12 + FPC 2.6.2

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Postgres 9.1